# WildFly10 shutdown error WFLYHC0181

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10, undertow

I am using wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip, start in domain mode in CentOS 6.6, some how it will shutdown accidently and the error as below:

> 2017-05-15 21:01:20,103 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Thread-2) WFLYHC0181: Host Controller shutdown has been requested via an OS signal

what may cause this error,thank you

Answer (score 0):

These are likely the causes,

Ctrl+c, kill -HUP , kill -INT , kill -TERM , and or System.exit call